# GCDAsyncSocket scan of ports

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, asyncsocket

I have a problem with `GCDAsyncSocket`, to do a port scan the interface of the app freezes.
This is the code:

```
GCDAsyncSocket *clientSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self
delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSString *scanHostIP;

NSError *error = nil;

for(int i=1; i<=254; i++) {

    scanHostIP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.%d", i];
    [clientSocket connectToHost:scanHostIP onPort:1234 withTimeout:0.4 error:&error];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.4]];
}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.